# Typescript complaining about explicit type not having index signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

Typescript is raising the error `"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'HumansToDogs' has no index signature."` on the following code.

Everything seems explicit and straightforward to me, can anyone help?

```js
type HumanName = 'Jessie' | 'Mark';
type DogName = 'Spot' | 'Buddy';

type HumansToDogs = {
  [key in HumanName]: DogName;  // Isn't this an index signature?
}

const humansToDogs: HumansToDogs = {
  'Jessie': 'Buddy',
  'Mark': 'Spot',
};

for (const human in humansToDogs) {
  const dog = humansToDogs[human];  // Index signature error here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for..of` will type the loop variable as `string`. With `noImplicitAny` you can't index into a type with an arbitrary `string`. The simplest solution is to use a type assertion:

```
for (const human  in humansToDogs) {
    const dog = humansToDogs[human as HumanName];  // Index signature error here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly let the Typescript compiler know that `human` referes to a key of `HumanName` as follows:

```
humansToDogs[human as keyof HumanName]
```

But a better way is to define the shape of your data, you can explicitly define a new type that declares the index as a string:

```
type HumanNames = {[k: string] HumanName};
```